# install ionic framework with node.js v18.15.0 and npm v9.5.0, error at first installation

Tags: ionic-framework

Got a new MacBook Pro M2 (the old one was intel). I am trying to reinstall everything on my Mac. I am using ionic to build my Apps.

So I install node.js, LTS (18.15.0) then I install ionic using `npm uninstall -g ionic`

Then I create a first project with `ionic start` using Angular and I got an error while creating the project :

```
npm ERR! Found: @angular/router@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/router
npm ERR!   @angular/router@"^15.0.0" from the root project
```

Since everything is new n the computer, I do not get why something is wrong here, should I install something else ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: solve it, using sudo mode

Answer (score 0):

try this one might work, delete your node_modules folder in your project directory and package-lock.json file too. and try to clean your npm cache using "npm cache clean --force" and try to install all the dependencies again using npm install